# Поясните за коллбек без параметра

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

у меня вопрос на счет коллбеков. Как работает коллбек без параметров? Учусь по книге Node js в действии(2018 года), в ней приводятся примеры кода с комментариями. Как видите, в каждом статическом методе последним аргументом является cb. Я вроде как понял что коллбек это функция, которая вызовется когда отработает весь остальной код. Но в контексте данного кода это определение не совсем понятно. Особенно в местах, где просто вызывается cb(). Сразу скажу, что скинул не весь код, но в других местах коллбек не объявлен. Поэтому в общем-то я и не понимаю что он и зачем. Если бы было что-то вроде:

```
var cb = function(){
//экспекто патронум = призвать оленя()
}
```

То вопросов не возникло бы, а так...
Вот код из учебника чтобы лучше понять вопрос
Комментарии из него же, в скобках указываю что непонятно.

```
static getByName(name, cb){
        User.getId(name, (err, id)=>{   //Определяет идентификатор пользователя по имени
            if(err) return cb(err)
            User.getByName(id, cb)   //Получает данные пользователя по идентификатору (что здесь делает cb?)
        })
    }
    static getId(name, cb){
        db.get(`user:id${name}`, cb) //Получает идентификатор индексированием по имени (и здесь?)
    }
    static get(id, cb){
        db.hgetall(`user:${id}`, (err, user)=>{   //получает данные в виде простого объекта 
            if(err) return cb(err)  //(cb(err) я так понимаю работает как new Error?)
            cb(null, new User(user))  //Преобразует простой объект в новый объект User
        })
    }
    static authenticate (name, pass, cb){
        User.getByName(name, (err, user)=>{   //Проводит поиск пользователя по имени
            if(err) return cb(err)
            if(!user.id) return cb()  //Пользователь не существует (и здесь?)
            bcrypt.hash(pass, user.salt, (err, hash)=>{  //Хэширует введенный пароль
                if(err) return cb(err)
                if(hash === user.pass) return cb(null, user)  //Обнаружено совпадение
                cb()  //Неверный пароль (Неверный пароль ок, а cb() что делает?
            })

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Эти методы получают какие-то данные. Получать-то получают, но использовать полученные данные как-то нужно потом. Если метод асинхронный, то данные доступны не сразу, поэтому применяются коллбэки. То, что они указаны без круглых вызывающих скобок, означает, что вместо них будет какая-то реальная функция, заданная вами. То есть в данном случае cb - это ссылка на какую-то функцию (в будущем вашу). Далее cb вызывается с аргументами или без. Это обычное дело, и есть соглашение в ноде насчёт аргумента err (всегда первого по порядку). Когда имеется err, значит ошибка, когда его нет, то можно смело продолжать в вашей функции что-то делать.

Теперь ваши вопросы по порядку:

> что здесь делает cb?

Он будет вызван после того, как User.getByName получит данные, и в этот колбэк вторым аргументом забросит эти данные (скорее всего), так как первый аргумент всегда зарезервирован для ошибки (err).

> и здесь?

Да, то же самое по сути.

> cb(err) я так понимаю работает как new Error?

Нет. Ошибка уже имеется к данному моменту и она просто помещается в первый аргумент функции по нодовскому соглашению.

> Неверный пароль (Неверный пароль ок, а cb() что делает?

Вызывается без объекта юзера, соответсвенно вы должны его в своей функции проверять. Однако тут спорный момент, не понятно почему в данном случае там не сделана ошибка `cb( Error('user not found') )` или подобная.

Вызывать эти методы можно так:

```
User.getByName( 'Vasia', ( err, user )=>{
    if( err || !user ) return; // прерываем свои действия
    .... // а тут пишем действия если всё норм
});
```

Comment: Вот и я  о том-же, по логике в нем должны быть какие-то действия определены, а так он просто вызвался и все. Пользуясь случаем хочу спросить, по какой книге лучше ноду осваивать? А то что-то мне подсказывает что эта книжечка для более шаристых ребят писалась.Спасибо за ответ, сейчас уже голова не хочет думать, проснусь еще раз перечитаю то что вы написали и попробую перенести это на пример может соображу к чему их тут вызывали

Comment: @OleksiiKravets, книгу не подскажу, думаю что нужно скорее js учить, тогда и нода будет понятна. В частности ваш вопрос относится полностью к js, а не к ноде.

Comment: н будет вызван после того, как User.getByName получит данные, и в этот колбэк вторым аргументом забросит эти данные (скорее всего), так как первый аргумент всегда зарезервирован для ошибки (err). Куда он их забросит то? в себя? Результат работы функции другая функция которая вызовется в коллбеке или как? Вызывается с аргументами - обычное дело, вы имеете в виду что в коллбеке даже если не передать никакого параметра то будет дефолтный параметр ошибки?

Comment: Если учить js, посоветуете как? Просто пока что сколько не учил - начал понимать базовые вещи, могу объяснить простой код, но как научиться именно писать а не переписывать автора? Я имею в виду что я когда прохожу материал то понимаю что он пишет в плане: Вот колбек, а вот промис, а вот тут массив. Но нет понимания того, почему он так пишет, как он придумал этот код? Вот как перейти от стадии "Переписыватель кода" до стадии "Создатель кода"?

Comment: В чате можем обсудить, там объясняю - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106997/

Comment: Я перешел по ссылке но не понимаю как написать, нет поля ввода текста

Comment: А все понял, у меня репутации нет чтобы чатиться=( облом. А есть тут личные сообщения? или что-то типа того

Comment: @OleksiiKravets, теперь есть